# Why do we need passing by reference when overloading ">>" and "<<"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I didn't understand very well why we need reference before the istreams and ostreams (in all 4 of them in my code). I've kind of understood why the ones that are function arguments need ampersant, because the copy constructors is not allowed to act on ostream and istream, so they need reference, but why do the ones that specify the type that is returned? I really can not figure that out, and moreover, i can't understand why the code doesn't even compile if I remove the ampersants from them ( I get this error: *error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'foo')*).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    int x;

 public:
    foo()
    {
        x=10;
    }
 
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, foo& S);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, foo& S);
    
};

istream& operator>>(istream& in, foo& S)
    {
        in>>S.x;
        return in; 
    }

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, foo& S)
    {
        out<<S.x;
        return out;
    }

int main()
{

    foo A, B, C;

    cin>>A;

    cout<<A;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Copies of streams are a bad idea, and I believe that you can't even copy streams anyway.

Comment: If you input stream overload didn't take `foo` by reference, how would you change the objecrt used in the call site?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You already know that you need references in the function arguments because you can't copy streams, so why would you be able to copy a stream when *returning* from a function?

Comment: As for the type, with `operator>>()`, do you want to input the data into a copy that gets destroyed when you leave the function, or do you want to put information into the object in question? You need to understand what the difference is between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, and I feel like your question would just answer itself.

Comment: You would also want `const foo&` in `operator<<` under normal circumstances since you will not normally be changing the object you are streaming.

Comment: It's the same concept when returning - without a reference, a copy will be returned. It's not a good idea to copy cin/cout.

Answer (score 0):

The streams are not copyable.  Parameters without reference or pointer are passed by copy.

In general, if the parameter is larger than a processor's register, pass it by reference, to avoid copying.  Large objects take a lot of time to copy, especially when they don't need to be copied.  This is why pointers were created; pointers are faster to copy than the large objects.

The input stream parameters should be passed by reference since they will both be modified.

The object parameter should be passed by constant reference since it will not be modified.

Comment: OP can just try it and see the error: https://godbolt.org/z/hnf7T6eP5